# React app "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" when running in prod

Tags: reactjs, react-native, docker, web, web-applications

I cannot seem to solve this issue I am having with React. In development mode, my react app works fine. When I try to run it in production with Docker, it does not work. So I tried checking the index.html and when I open it I see two "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" error messages as well as "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT" with some kind of facebook link?

I used a template when making the react app.

Any ideas why I am getting the uncaught syntax error? Please let me know, any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the homepage line entirely from the package.json in the react app directory fixed it somehow.

good luck to anyone with similar issue.